# C1ReportViewer remove special characters (nagative "-" sign and "(") from SSRS

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, componentone

So I have some SSRS reports that are done in Visual 2008. they look fine in the report viewer. but then I user ComponentOne, C1ReportViewer any negative numbers show up with a space after the number on the repot. so "-123" would look like "123 " I would really like to have () around the - numbers but the () gets striped out as well.

Please help
Danny

Answer (score 0):

This can be a bug with C1Reportviewer. I would suggest you to report on their forums.
http://our.componentone.com/groups/

Thanks,
Richa